# How to override base url when creating links to public files?

Tags: 7, hooks, files, theming

I need storage the upload into drupal file in another server and I need change public path to files to example http://server_with_image/image How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically describing the use case of a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

Check [CDN](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) module:

> This module provides easy Content Delivery Network integration for Drupal sites. It alters file URLs, so that files are downloaded from a CDN instead of your web server.
>
> It provides two modes: "Origin Pull" and "File Conveyor".
>
> - In Origin Pull mode, only "Origin Pull" CDNs are supported. (These are CDNs that only require you to replace the domain name with another domain name.)
> - In File Conveyor mode, this module integrates with File Conveyor, which allows for much more advanced setups (e.g. optimize images, transcode videos, and so on, before syncing to the CDN).

Comment: I havent CDN server Like amazon and else? You sure that module works for me?

Comment: The concept of CDN is not limited to any particular server. Check http://wimleers.com/article/key-properties-of-a-cdn for more info